# while converting date into date object showing NaN in place of date in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

i am having a date format coming from server which shows date and time like this : "Thu Jan 07 2016 11:00:40 GMT+0530 (IST)" , i have converted that date into this format "1/7/2016 11:00 am" . the problem i am facing is i want a date to me in the format of mm/dd/yyyy along with time in am and pm 12 hour format , it is displaying me the date in this format only in the chrome browser . but when i tried creating build of the project in i pad its showing me "Nan " in place of date and time .

Kindly help.

this is my code for date:

this function converts my date into dd/mm/yyyy format and 12 hour format time.

```
  function formatDate(date) {
                var hours = date.getHours();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                hours = hours % 12;
                hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
                var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
                return date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
                }
```

this code extracts the date from the json and converts it into specified format.

```
                           var date = new Date(data.Steps.records[i].CreatedDate);

                            //console.log("my date" + typeof(data.Steps.records[i].CreatedDate));
                            var convertedDate = formatDate(date);
                            console.log("my new date " + convertedDate);
                            data.Steps.records[i].CreatedDate = convertedDate;
                            // console.log("format" + data.Steps.records[i].CreatedDate);
                            console.log("date is :" + date);
```

Comment: i tried doing like that : var utcstring =date.toUTCString(); its showing me the format like :"Thu, 07 Jan 2016 05:30:40 GMT" , now i want to re convert it to mm/dd/yyyy and 12 hour format , can anybody tell me how ? –

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `data.Steps.records[i].CreatedDate` is something like "Thu Jan 07 2016 11:00:40 GMT+0530 (IST)" then you are trying to parse a string using the Date constructor. That isn't a good idea as parsing of such strings is largely implementation dependent, so even if it works in one host it may not work in another.

You should parse strings manually, either using your own function or a library.

Once you have the date created correctly, you can then create a formatted string, noting that it will be based on the systems settings of the host (i.e. a "lolcal" date).

A function to parse the format in the OP is below, though if you have many strings with different formats a library may make life easier (though a more general parser isn't hard to write):

```js
var s = "Thu Jan 07 2016 11:00:40 GMT+0530 (IST)"
var t = "Thu Jan 07 2016 01:10:50 GMT+0530 (IST)"
var u = "Thu Jan 07 2016 01:40:10 GMT+0530 (IST)"

function parseDate(s) {

  // Map month names to numbers suitable for input to Date
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};

  // Get values from the string, split on space and colon
  var b = s.split(/[ :]/);

  // Get the offset value
  var offset = b[7].replace(/\D/g, '');

  // Get the offset sign
  var offSign = b[7].indexOf('+') == -1? 1 : -1;
  
  // Create a new Date and adjust the values by the offset
  return new Date(
    Date.UTC(b[3],                          // Use year directly
    months[b[1].toLowerCase().substr(0,3)], // Get month number from map
    b[2],                                   // Use day number directly
    +b[4] + (offset.substr(0,2)*offSign),   // Adjust hours for offset
    +b[5] + (offset.substr(2,2)*offSign),   // Adjust minutes for offset
    b[6]));                                 // Use seconds directly
}

// Format date as dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss a/p
function formatDate(d) {
  function z(n){return ('0'+n).slice(-2)}
  var hr = d.getHours();
  var ap = hr < 12? 'am' : 'pm';
  hr = hr%12 || 12;
  return z(d.getDate()) + '/' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear() +
         ' ' + z(hr) + ':' + z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + z(d.getSeconds()) + ' ' + ap;
}

document.write(formatDate(parseDate(s)) + '<br>' +
               formatDate(parseDate(t)) + '<br>' +
               formatDate(parseDate(u)));
```

#### Edit

Add function to format date string per OP.

Comment: i want this function to parse the date into mm/dd/yyyy format with 12 hour am/pm time format . i am new to js not able to understand you code deeply

Comment: i tried doing like that :  var utcstring =date.toUTCString(); its showing me the format like :"Thu, 07 Jan 2016 05:30:40 GMT" , now i want to re convert it to mm/dd/yyyy and 12 hour format , can anybody tell me how ?

Comment: The provided function just parses the format in the OP to a Date, you can pass that to your *formatDate* function to get the format you require. I've added a function to format the date string as you required, it's essentially a more concise version of your function.

Comment: will it work for safari and ios devices bcz i am facing this problem specifically on ipad and safari browsers